# JMeter Script- Connection timed out

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner

I am receiving the below error when trying to run a JMeter script . The  API works fine in Loadrunner  .
I had set the https.default.protocol=TLSv1.2 in user.properties for the SSL version. What could cause the below error .

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to rXXXXX.XXXX-XXXX.XXXXXX.net:443 [XXXXXX.XXXXXX-XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX/21.60.245.182] failed: Connection timed out: connect
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$JMeterDefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HTTPHC4Impl.java:326)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:850)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:561)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you send the same request you should get the same response no matter what tool is being used for sending the request.

If you're getting different responses or not getting a response either you're sending not the same request or there is a difference in the tools configuration.

1. The most possible reason could be [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), by default Loadrunner respects underlying operating system proxy settings and in JMeter you need to configure the upstream proxy connection manually, see [Using JMeter behind a proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html) article for more details
2. Another reason could be incorrect request configuration, i.e. protocol/host/port/path mismatch
3. And last but not the least, maybe your connect/response timeouts are too low, try ramping them up, the relevant setting lives under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

   [image]

Comment: I am now running JMeter from behind a proxy . Now am receiving the below error Response code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException
Response message:Non HTTP response message: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that whatever the endpoint you try to access with this Jmeter script does not expect mutual SSL validation.
2. Then make sure that your token is generated from CA signed token generator before making the request.
3. Make sure that your connection timeout is not enough to respond after the request is made and make sure that the timeout is larger than the ramp-up time period.